# Manual SQL Query from Form Type / Abstract Class

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

First of all, I am moving from Symfony 1.4 to Symfony 3.  (Yes, I was kicking and screaming at first)

My Question:  I am running a manual query from the following FormType class that is for a chunk of my Signup form.  I am moving the Address part of the signup into its own class.  I am calling a geographical table to get my states list and I have a Union... hence this is why I am not calling an entity class.

The problem is that I need to connect to the database but cannot because it's an Abstract class.  If I run this in the Controller Class, no problem, but can't do it herein this Abstract class.  I have a bunch of manual steps to go through before making any inserts, so I can just

How do you make the following work?  I have not created any services, but if I put all of this into a controller class, then it works fine.

```
<?php

namespace LocationBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;


class PartialAddressType extends AbstractType
{
    private function getStatesList()
    {
        $sql = "
                SELECT
                 '0' AS id  
                 ,'' AS name
                 ,'' AS abbreviation
                 ,'Select State' AS display
                UNION
                SELECT
                  id
                 ,trim(name)
                 ,trim(abbreviation)
                 ,CONCAT(trim(abbreviation), ' - ', trim(name)) AS display
                FROM
                  geo_state
                WHERE
                  type = 'state'
                ORDER BY abbreviation ASC; ";

        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
        $conn = $manager->getConnection();
        $rs = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll();

        return $rs;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $rs = $this->getStatesList();


        //  This one is for a Select
        $builder->add('locationState', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'expanded'          => FALSE,
                'multiple'          => FALSE,
                'choices'           => $rs(),
                'choice_label'      => $rs['display'],
                'choice_attribute'  => $rs['abbreviation'],
                'preferred_choices' => array('TX'),
                'choices_as_values' => FALSE,
                'label'             => 'State',
            )
        );
   }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'location_bundle_partial_address_type';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you following steps:

1) Move the query in a separate repository class (I hope you map the table as an entity)

2) Use an EntityType Field with the Custom query as [described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)

3) Avoid the UNION using the [placeholder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder)

Last tips, You should implements the `getBlockPrefix` method instead of `getName` as described in the migration guide [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form).

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I will pursue this today and get back to you with the results.

Comment: Hi @TomOlson you are welcome! Good luck with the migration!